# How to delete an entire row if it is all 0's in R

Tags: r

If i have a data frame like so

```
4   6
6   0
4   5
0   0
6   5
0   4
4   4
```

But a lot bigger, what command can I write that will delete any row that is completely 0's, such as row 4 in my example.

In the end it would look like this

```
4   6
6   0
4   5
6   5
0   4
4   4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
df[apply(df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)], 1, function(x) !all(x==0)), ]
```

or

```
df[rowSums(abs(df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)])) != 0, ]
```

Example:

```
> df <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 0), y=c(0, 1, 0), z=letters[1:3])
> df
  x y z
1 1 0 a
2 2 1 b
3 0 0 c

> df[rowSums(abs(df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)])) != 0, ]
  x y z
1 1 0 a
2 2 1 b
```

Comment: didn't work... I don't want to delete all zeros, only rows that are completely 0s

Comment: Thanks for correcting, however it still doesn't work. I like the second option but since some of my columns are numerical and some are character vectors it doesn't work either :(

Comment: If so, please provide  an example data, optimally using `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: Or try (building on @zero323's solution) `df[apply(df, 1, function(x) !all(as.numeric(x)==0)), ]`. But since your example only included numbers, nobody knew to take character vectors into account....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
df <- df[-which(rowSums(abs(df)) == 0),]
#> df
#  X1 X2
#1  4  0
#2  6  6
#3  6  5
#5  4  4
#6  5  4
#7  0  4
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(c(4, 6, 6, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 6, 5, 0, 4, 4, 4), ncol=2))
```